# Spring Integration - File Inbound Adapter - set id

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration-dsl

Does anyone know how you can setup the id for an FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec?

This is how I am building the inbound adapter:

```
Files.inboundAdapter(new File("etc")).nioLocker().preventDuplicates();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to setup an id for the flow, when registering it to the integrationFlowContext.

Sample:
    this.integrationFlowContext.registration(flow).id(flowId).autoStartup(false).register();